# Help checking a fairly simple probabilitistic calculation

Tags: probability

Suppose there are two classes A and B and the heights of the students in class A are distributed $N(160,9)$ while the heights of the students in class B are distributed $N(170,9)$. Additionally there are twice as many students in class B as there are in class A. A student is sampled from the pool of both classes and it is found his height is $X$.

1) Given that $X\geq 163$ what is the probability that the the student came from class A - Is  the following calculation correct?
$$\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X\geq163\right)=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(A\ ,\ X\geq163\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\right)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(A\ ,\ X\geq163\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ M\right)\mathbb{P}\left(M\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ H\right)\mathbb{P}\left(H\right)}
=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(A\right)\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ A\right)}{\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ A\right)\mathbb{P}\left(A\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ B\right)\mathbb{P}\left(B\right)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ A\right)}{\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ A\right)+\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ B\right)}$$
 We know the distributions of the heights given the class and using an appropriate calculator gives $$\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ A\right)=1-\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq163\ |\ A\right)=0.15866$$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ B\right)=1-\mathbb{P}\left(X\leq163\ |\ B\right)=0.99$$
  plug this in and we get $$\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X\geq163\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\cdot0.15866}{\frac{1}{3}\cdot0.15866+\frac{2}{3}\cdot0.99}=0.07419$$

2) Given that $X=163$ what is the probability the student came from class $A$. - It seems to me that due to the continuity of the distributions in question this probability should be zero. Unless I'm mistaken the following calculation also confirms this
$$\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X>163\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{P}\left(X>163\ |\ A\right)}{\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{P}\left(X>163\ |\ A\right)+\frac{2}{3}\mathbb{P}\left(X>163\ |\ B\right)}$$
 As these are continuous distributions we have that $$\mathbb{P}\left(X>163\ |\ A\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ A\right)$$
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X>163\ |\ B\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X\geq163\ |\ B\right)$$
 Thus $\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X>163\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X\geq163\right)$
  which means that $$\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X=163\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X\geq163\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(A\ |\ X>163\right)=0$$

I would appreciate it if someone could confirm or correct my reasoning.

Comment: The first calculation is in outline right. (I have not checked the numbers.) The second calculation is not right, the probability is not $0$. You can work with conditional probabilities for the second problem. I sort of prefer to say that the probability that a class A student is between $163$ and $163+h$, or if you prefer $163+\Delta x$, is roughly the density function times $h$. Calculate as in the first problem. The $h$'s will cancel. (In principle we are taking a limit).  Note that the last displayed equation is not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for replying. I'm not sure exactly what you mean about taking roughly the density function times $h$. If I were to try and calculate the probability of the height being in the interval $[163,163+h]$ I would have to integrate the density (which I can't really do as that integral has no closed form) and even if I did that by continuity if I take the limit when $h\to0$ i would end up with $0$. I think I didn't get you intent correctly.

Comment: The first-order approximation to the area (probability) is the density function times $h$. Calculate the approximate conditional probability that the student is in Class A, using the $(1/3)f_A(163)h$ in the numerator and $(1/3)f_A(163)h+(2/3)f_B(163) h$ in the denominator. The $h$'s cancel. In reality both top and bottom have terms that go to $0$ faster than $h$, and we are taking the limit as $h\to 0$. There is also a formal way to do this, which I hope someone will give. I wanted to stress the intuition.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank again, i see what you mean now. Is there any chance you would be willing to formalize this so that I could see the more formal solution also?